# How to build Custom directive similar to ng-model?

Tags: angularjs

I want to build a directive that work same as `ng-model` directive.I tried it using `$watch`, but can't able to build. Can anyone help me in this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `ng-model` is there so why you need a new one ?

Comment: when there was no-mg-model someone build it. I also want to build the same. what is problem in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

JS:

```
app.directive('simpleMOdel', function (){
return function (scope,elem,attrs) {
var modelGetter = $parse(attrs.simpleMOdel);
var modelsetter =modelGetter.assign;
scope.$watch(modelGetter,function(newVal,oldVal){
elem.val(newVal);
});
//DOM model updates
elem.bind('input',function () {
modelSetter(scope,elem.val())
})
}
})
```

HTML:

```
<input  simple-model='name'>
<span simple-model-bind="name"></span>
```